# Push git changes to a shared network drive, data on remote repository not visible

Tags: git

I do have a local repository on my local drive and a remote repository on my network drive.
Everything is working, i can push data to the remote repository (bare repository) and my colleague is able to pull my data from the remote repository on the shared network drive. There is just one mystery. I do not see the data on the remote repository on the network drive? Is the data in a different form in the objects folder?

i expected if i push sth to the remote repository on the network drive it will appear (data ist visible) on the remote repository.

Comment: chances are it was initialized as a bare repository, this means you will find `config`, `objects/`, `refs/` etc ... directly in `./` instead of within a `.git/` subdirectory. You can run `git config core.bare` and see if it says `true`, or just run `ls` and see for yourself.

Comment: @LeGEC's point is valid.... and _also_, consider that even if it's not a bare repo, things won't magically happen just because you push into a branch of a repo with a working tree.... if it has a working tree, git will by default reject trying to push into the branch that is checked out in the working tree.